# .htaccess RewriteRule ^.*$ - [S=40] to Nginx

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I had https://github.com/lencioni/SLIR setup on appache. It has an htaccess file and works very well. Now i have moved to Nginx and want to have SLIR work the same way. Below is what i needed to convert.

```
# Prevent other scripts from interfering with SLIR
php_value auto_prepend_file none
php_value auto_append_file none

# Pretty URLs
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [S=40]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# Prevent viewing of the error log file in its default location
<Files slir-error-log>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
</Files>
```

I was able to convert everything except the line below

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [S=40]
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: It's better to ask this question on superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (!-f $request_filename) { rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last; } # check for file
if (!-d $request_filename) { rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last; } # check for dir
```

**EDIT** checked on my server - this single line works for both, (dir and file)

```
if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php last; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `S` flag tells mod_rewrite to skip some number of the following rules (in your case, it's **40**). You can alternatively change your rules around to be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Might be easier to convert.